# How to avoid unnecessary copies when initializing vectors with variadic templates

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, c++-templates

In my project, I'm facing the initializing vectors with variadic template. However, I found that some unnecessary or unexpected copies could happen in follow code (in function `create_elements` and `create_dummies`).

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <any>

struct Dummy {
  int x;
  Dummy() = default;
  Dummy(Dummy&&) = default;
  Dummy(const Dummy& d) {
    x = d.x;
    static int count = 0;
    printf("copy dummy %d, times: %d\n", x, ++count);
  }
  Dummy(int x) : x(x) {}
};

template<typename... Comps> std::vector<std::any> create_elements (Comps&&... value) {
  return {std::make_any<Comps>(std::forward<Comps>(value))...};
}

template<typename... Dummies> std::vector<Dummy> create_dummies (Dummies&&... value) {
  return {std::forward<Dummies>(value)...};
}

int main() {
  create_dummies(Dummy(1));
  create_elements(Dummy(2));
  std::vector<Dummy> w;
  w.emplace_back(std::move(Dummy(3)));
  return 0;
}
```

In above example, after compiling and running will result in

```
copy dummy 1, times: 1
copy dummy 2, times: 2
```

, which means that `create_elements` and `create_dummies` call the copy constructor of Dummy.
What I expect is that these two methods will have the same behaviors as the `emplace_back` solution (no copy called). What should I do, or why can't I do that? thanks!

Comment: The reason for the copies is because the returned vector is constructed by a constructor overload that takes a `std::initializer` list as a parameter. The `std::initializer_list` is passed by value. I see no reason why the values cannot be moved into a vector. Yet, `std::initializer_list`'s iterator reference `const` values, that prevents a move. There is no way to prevent a copy when using a braced init list to construct a vector. This is a defect.

Comment: it's feasible to workaround - https://godbolt.org/z/oEdf89Yve

Comment: Thanks to this [article](https://tristanbrindle.com/posts/beware-copies-initializer-list). I try to use `emplace_back` to construct the vector, which solves my problem. ```c++ ```